# Ativar input com tecla enter

Tags: java, jquery, funções, teclado

Boa tarde, esotu tentando criar um sistema de login e para entrar no sistema ao clicar a tecla enter no teclado, acaba redirecionando para o meu "esqueci minha senha" além de ativar a tecla "entrar".

eu mudo o o esqueci senha para "button" funciona, porém quebra uma outra coisa.
preciso que os dois fiquem como "submit e consiga ativar o button de entrar ao clicar enter no teclado

segue o codigo:

```
<div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                   
                                                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 9%; margin-top: 1%">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-link" id="btnSenha" data-toggle="modal" onserverclick="btnSenha_click" runat="server" type="submit"><strong>Esqueci minha senha</strong></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <div class="text-center" style="padding-bottom: 5%; width: 90%; padding-left: 9%">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onserverclick="ImageAcessar_Click" id="ImageAcessar" runat="server" type="submit"><strong>Entrar</strong></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para recuperar o evento do enter no teclado pode usar algo como o código abaixo:

```
document.querySelector("#botao").addEventListener("evento", handler)

var keyCode = ''
function handler(event) {
    keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which
    if(keyCode == 13) {
       console.log('pressionei o enter')
    }
})
```

cada botão você poderia recuperar com o ajax e lançar dois eventos distintos de submit

Comment: você poderia montar pra min? sou fraco em javacript nao entendo muito.

Comment: claro, irei enviar um exemplo que construi

Answer (score -1):

fiz um exemplo básico para um botão, você pode replicar para o outro da mesma forma, segue o código html de exemplo:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="nome"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="btn_entrar">Entrar</button>
</body>

</html>
```

O JS fica dessa forma, onde estiver o comentário //substituir pela função que pretende usar basta adicionar a função de submit do formulário com ajax.

```
$(function() {

  $('button[name="btn_entrar"]').click(function() {
    alert('testando ...!');
    //substituir pela função que pretende usar | o ultimo código dessa resposta entra aqui
  });

  $('#nome').keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) // enter
    {
      $('button[name = btn_entrar]').click();
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

a função pra enviar o formulário seria mais ou menos assim

```
 $("form").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
         url: '/entrar',
         type: 'POST',
         data: $(this).serialize()
         }).done(function (response) {
         
           //fazer algo com o retorno
         })
 
        
    });
```